# Inserting object literal into array

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the splice method isn't working for me. I have an array that looks like: (it is actually bigger but I didn't want to clutter the page)

```
var navItems = [ {
                    "content": "Panels",
                    "icon": "panels"
                },
                {
                    "content": "Samples",
                    "icon": "sample"
                }];
```

I want to insert an item say in the middle:

```
var testNavItems = navItems.splice(1, 0, {
                    "content": "New Nav",
                    "icon": "New Nav"
                   });
console.log(testNavItems);
```

OR

```
var testNavItems = navItems.push({
                    "content": "New Nav",
                    "icon": "New Nav"
                   });
console.log(testNavItems);
```

I get an empty array.  Is this possible in JS?

Comment: [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns the elements which have been removed, [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array. Always check the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.push` and `.splice` do not create a new array. They modify the original array.

Try

```
console.log(navItems);
```